# OpenMP detects only a single core on multi-socket/multi-core system

Tags: c++, openmp

I program in C++ and uses OpenMP for parallelization. The machine has 2 CPU sockets and 8 cores per each socket.

Since I compile with intel compiler, I set the following environment variables

```
export KMP_AFFINITY=verbose,scatter
```

With verbose option, I can see the following messages when running the binary.

```
[0] OMP: Info #204: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
[0] OMP: Info #202: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
[0] OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: {0}
[0] OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 1 available OS procs
[0] OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
[0] OMP: Info #159: KMP_AFFINITY: 1 packages x 1 cores/pkg x 1 threads/core (1 total cores)
[0] OMP: Info #206: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map:
[0] OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 0 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 14 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 15 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 11 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 6 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 7 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 8 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 9 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 10 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 13 bound to OS proc set {0}
[0] OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12759 thread 12 bound to OS proc set {0}
```

As you can see, OMP cannot detect the correct number of packages (sockets) and cores per package. As a result, all the threads are pinned to a single core.

How can I resolve this issue? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question.

My program sets the CPU affinity of the main thread as follows:

...

```
CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
CPU_SET(0, &cpuset);
pid_t tid = (pid_t) syscall(SYS_gettid);
sched_setaffinity(tid, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);

unsigned long mask = -1;
int rc = sched_getaffinity(tid, sizeof(unsigned long), (cpu_set_t*) &mask);
if (rc != 0) {
  std::cout << "ERROR calling pthread_setaffinity_np; " << rc << std::endl;
  abort();
}
```

...

The OpenMP threads spawned after the setaffinitiy syscall are all bound to the same core that the main thread is bound.